# Median primes and cryptography

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

I've been considering something involving median numbers.

If an integer is directly in the middle of two integers, is it possible to accurately extrapolate what two it is between?

Can a prime be in the middle of two primes?

Would this sort of information have any applications to digital cryptography?

Comment: Have you thought about it? Take the number $10$ for example. This is in between $9$ and $11$, or $8$ and $12$, or $7$ and $13$, and so on. There is no way to determine what the original two numbers were. Yes it is possible for a prime to be in the middle of two primes. For example $5$ in the middle of $3$ and $7$, or $7$ in the middle of $3$ and $11$, or $11$ in the middle of $5$ and $17$, and so on.

Comment: I thought about it. But imagine if we did this with a large number...it would be unfeasible to calculate what it is between, correct? Would this not be useful in crypto?

Comment: @user145271 You're not getting it, the size of the number doesn't matter. Any number is between infinitely many pairs of numbers. A correct answer doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you see why it's strange to ask if it's feasible to calculate, given it's not even possible *in principle* to determine?

Comment: So this obviously would not be usable in cryptography.

Comment: Your first line include the word "media." is that a shorthand for "median", or just a mistype?

Comment: I attempted to add the n at the end but apparently pushed the period key. Fixing it now

Comment: It's in fact known that there are _infinitely many_ primes that are 'in the middle of' two other primes; these are known as _arithmetic progressions_ of primes (specifically, arithmetic progressions of length 3); another example (in addition to Alexander Gruber's) is the sequence 5, 11, 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any number $n$ and it is between $n-1$ and $n+1$, and $n-2$ and $n+2$, and $n-3$ and $n+3$, and so on.  Asking "which number is $n$ in the middle of" has infinitely many answers. There are no applications to cryptography (or anything else) because the question is not well-defined.

To answer your second question, an example of a prime lying in the middle of two primes is $5$, which lies midway between $3$ and $7$.

Answer (score 0):

More interestingly all numbers (ie natural numbers) lie mid-way between two primes.  And that includes prime numbers as well.  The only proviso being that the number in question is 4 or greater, other wise there would not be any suitable primes smaller than it.

But as the target gets larger then it is in general likely to to lie between an increasing number of primes.  And that applies to the primes themselves.